# transfering token from one account to another

Tags: solidity

i wanted to move token from one account to the other but the transaction is pending, what should i do?

```
 pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract smart{
event TransformToken(
    address _source,
    address _destination,
    uint amount
    );
mapping (address => uint)account;

function showToken(address _address)public view returns(uint){
 uint token=account[_address];
 return (token);

}
function addToken(address _address,uint amount)public{
 account[_address]+=amount;
 }
 function subToken(address _address,uint amount)public{
 account[_address]-=amount;
}

 function transfer(address _address,uint amount)public view returns(uint){
   addToken(_address,amount);
   subToken(msg.sender,amount);
   emit TransformToken(msg.sender,_address,amount);
   return showToken(_address);
   } 
  }
```

[image: token pendding]

Comment: Well your `transfer` function is useless here, as it is a `view`. It will not save anything to contract and won't emit events, so `TransformToken` event will not be fired, `addToken` and `subToken` functions will not increase actual values in contract `storage`.

Answer (score 1):

you are declaring transfer as a view function, this prevents it from altering state.
It should work if you remove the view modifier.

https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/contracts.html#view-functions